# Bluetooth socket returns WSAEPROTONOSUPPORT

Tags: c++, sockets, bluetooth, windows-ce

For a project I am working on I would like to have an Embedded System to act as a Bluetooth server. I got the driver for my USb-Bluetooth working and in the Control Panel I now have a "Bluetooth Device Properties"-option which works and detects other devices via the Bluetooth USB dongle.

However when I try to use the dongle in code, I get an error.

The Includes are:

winsock2.h, ws2bth.h, bt_sdp.h, bthapi.h, bt_api.h, winioctl.h, windows.h

This is the code:

```
int Main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     WSADATA wsd;
     if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd)){
         wprintf(L"Initialization of socket subsystem failed! Error = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
         return 0;
     }
     SOCKET server = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
     if(server == INVALID_SOCKET){
         printf("socket failed, error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
         return 0;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

This compiles, but when running it fails at the socket creation. GetLastError returns 10043, which means WSAEPROTONOSUPPORT. A quick search gives me this list with error codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The code runs on a normal laptop with bluetooth, so I suspect it has something to do with the driver or so. 
Any help is appreciated!

Kind Regards

Comment: The error is clear: protocol not supported. You have to use something else instead of `SOCK_STREAM`. From where are you getting `AF_BTH` and `BTHPROTO_RFCOMM`? From your bluetooth headers I imagine. Probably there is also the protocol to be used there. Instead try with `SOCK_RAW`

Comment: @KevinD: just because you have a Bluetooth USB driver working in the Control Panel does not guarantee you have a Bluetooth Service Provider installed for WinSock. They are two different things. On the othr hand, have a look at [Creating a Connection to a Remote Device Using a Virtual COM Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881004.aspx) if WinSock is not working for you. Which version of WinCE are you using?  [WinCE 5.0 supports Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898944.aspx).

Comment: @salvolds: [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362910.aspx) says: "*To create a socket using Bluetooth, use the following settings: •The `af` parameter of the `socket()` function is always set to `AF_BTH` for Bluetooth sockets. •The `type` parameter of the `socket()` function is always `SOCK_STREAM`; `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets are not supported by Bluetooth. •For the `protocol` parameter, `BTHPROTO_RFCOMM` is the supported protocol.*"  Also see [Creating a Connection to a Remote Device Using Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881660.aspx).

Comment: I can confirm that `AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM` work on WEC 7.0. I wrote a Bluetooth server a while back that uses the same parameters except only requesting WinSock 1.1, not 2.2 (though that shouldn't make any difference). My guess - though I could be wrong - is you would need to add SYSGEN_BTH_PAN to your OS image to enable Winsock support

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I tried the Virtual COM Port and instead of RegisterDevice, I used RegisterBluetoothCOMPort. This compiles, but when I try to run it II get "Unable to import library COREDLL.dll ! Program will exit.". The COREDLL.dll is present in /Windows on the embedded device.

Comment: @Carsten Hansen: I also suspect it being something in the configuration of the OS we use. I will look into this.